# Flexbox define width of columns and align left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox in order to create equal width columns. I am setting flex to flex: 1 1 200px; on each item. When the number of items in each row are not equal, the items in the row with the smaller amount of items are spread out to fill the space (test 7 and test 8 in image below).

[image]

In the above image I would like the test7 item to only fill the space of the test 1 row and I would like the test 8 column to only fill the space of the test2 column.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.eqWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.eq {
  padding: 10px;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: yellow;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.equalHW {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="equalHWrap eqWrap">
  <div class="equalHW eq">test1</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test2</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test3</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test4</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test5</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test6</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test7</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test8</div>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/jesouhaite08/pen/ajooYq

Comment: it's working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this would be to simply give your `.eq` elements a `max-width` of `200px`. This can be applied to all `.eq` elements (as can be seen in the following), or exclusively applied to elements 7 and 8, by adding an additional class.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.eqWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.eq {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width:200px;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: yellow;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.equalHW {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="equalHWrap eqWrap">
  <div class="equalHW eq">test1</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test2</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test3</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test4</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test5</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test6</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test7</div>
  <div class="equalHW eq">test8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your information.
If you want to fixed the width that you set, set 0 to flex-grow and flex-shrink, like flex: 0 0 200px;.